# How I can get BCL format of timezone by passing it TZ format

Tags: javascript, c#, internationalization, timezone, nodatime

we are using Nodatime assembly for conversion time to specified time zones. but I am using JavaScript to get users time zone using following code `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`
but it returns me tz format of timezone but I want timezone name in BCL format to pass it to database.
is there any way to get bcl timezone name by passing tz timezone name?

Comment: https://www.iana.org/time-zones